# Can't install nvidia driver 340 ( GT 230M )

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia

I am trying to install nvidia drivers on my laptop which has GT 230 M GPU.

My laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04

It sounds that there is conflict between nvidia driver and some other package installed

I am getting this error

```
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-340_340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib' with
  different file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new nvidia-340 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried this command and it did not work

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force installation of the problematic deb package with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-340_340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

and then resume package installation:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```